# PHP Notice: Undefined index: filter_name - Opencart 1.5.6.1

Tags: php, search, undefined, opencart

Hope you someone can help me out here. I was running opencart 1.5.4 and had to upgrade version to 1.5.6.1 with a new hosting account. Since then my search isn't working through header search box.

I have been using a vqmod which modified search to include AND rather OR, so it returns results such as "hp p1105" (my site is a printer cartridges website) in the previous version of 1.5.4. Since the upgrade to 1.5.6.1 header search isn't returning any results.

For an example; if you search "hp p1005" by going to [new hosting account link](http://64.34.75.145/~sydne716/) it won't show you any results and return `http://64.34.75.145/~sydne716/index.php?route=product/search&search=hp%20p1005`.

But if I modify the same returned link to include filter_name then it shows up results as expected. `http://64.34.75.145/~sydne716/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=hp%20p1005`

Also if I search in the search results page again, it returns all search items.

I have tried posting on opencart forum, got few replies but nothing seem to help to resolve the issue I'm having. [Opencart forum link](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=151008)

I also get below error in the system --> error section

2015-09-13 20:22:20 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: filter_name in /home/sydne716/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_model_catalog_product.php on line 481

I would really appreciate if someone can help here. I'm waiting to use my new hosting account but without search working I can't go ahead.

Thank you, and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `catalog/view/javascript/common.js` change:

```
$('.button-search').bind('click', function() {
    url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

    var search = $('input[name=\'search\']').attr('value');

    if (search) {
        url += '&search=' + encodeURIComponent(search);
    }

    location = url;
});
```

to:

```
$('.button-search').bind('click', function() {
    url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

    var search = $('input[name=\'search\']').attr('value');

    if (search) {
        // NOTE: search was changed to filter_name
        url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(search);
    }

    location = url;
});
```

Do the same change to `$('#header input[name=\'search\']').bind('keydown', function(e) {`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My common.js already have $filter_name included.

Comment: In the page you provided there is no `filter_name`. Can you please recheck? you can check it by `view source`->click on that common.js file. Maybe you should clear some cache on server?

Comment: if (search) {
   url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(search);
  }

Comment: Sorry but I still see `search` instead of `filter_name`.. `'&search=' + encodeURIComponent(search);`. Maybe you forgot to push the file on server?

Comment: yes you are correct. For some reason common.js file on the server wasn't the one I had with my backups. I have made the change, I can see filter_name coming up now. But still search doesn't return anything. I also noticed that returned url changed to http://64.34.75.145/~sydne716/index.php?route=product/search

Comment: That's because your input has the name `search` but in the javascript code you are trying to get the filter by `$('input[name=\'filter_name\']').attr('value')`.. Fix it by changing the name of the input to `filter_name`

Comment: all good now. I had to include url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search&description=true'; as my backup file common.js. Thank you so much for your help and appreciate taking time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

I get same problem after removing `<base>` tag. To fix edit `catalog/view/javascript/common.js`. Replace:

```
$('base').attr('href')
```

with:

```
location.protocol + "//" + location.host + '/'
```

Another aproach to fix it using .htaccess:

```
# === fix router error ===
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^(.*)_route_=undefined[^&]*&(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R,L]
```